# How do i add spacing between each row of textbutton.icons

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am still new to dart, I didn't put all the buttons in rows but I would like to add spacing between each row of buttons. How would I go about doing this? Here is some of my code:

```
class Button1 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: TextButton.icon(
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 75,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                'Contact Us',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        label: Text(
          '', //'Label',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Button2 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: TextButton.icon(
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 75,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                'Calendar',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

How would I add spacing between Button1 and Button2 without using padding.

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68698735/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: Do you mean that `Button1` and `Button2` will be Row's children ? can you include the Ui that you like to archive?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your buttons Row with Padding widget like below. This will put spacing on top.

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
    child: Row(
        children: [
            // your buttons here
        ]
    ),
)
```

Comment: I cant use padding otherwise it says it overflowed