# Need to add spacing between the two row values

Tags: flutter

```
BlocBuilder<VoiceChatCubit, VoiceChatState>(
        buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
            previous.myClientRole != current.myClientRole,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              if (state.myClientRole == ClientRole.Broadcaster)
                InkWell(
                  onTap: context.read<VoiceChatCubit>().toggleMute,
                    child: 
                    Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          offset: const Offset(
                            0,
                            3.0,
                          ),
                          blurRadius: 1.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0,
                        ),
                   ],
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: border_color,
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                  child:
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: BlocBuilder<VoiceChatCubit, VoiceChatState>(
                      buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                          previous.canListen != current.canListen,
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        return Icon(
                          state.canListen
                              ? Icons.volume_up
                              : Icons.volume_off,
                          color:
                              state.canListen ? Colors.black : Colors.red,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

Need to add spacing between the two values in the row over here. Tried mainaxisalignment didn't work, also Space() in case I could add spacing between the two values but don't know where to add them.
Added the entire row values: I tried the main.axis alignment didn't separate the two, they stick together in this.

Comment: Which two "row values" do you mean? What do you mean with "row value"? Your row currently only has maximum one element in its children, which is an InkWell.

Comment: you can also try with sizedBox `SizedBox(width: 10)` and you can share more code for better understanding

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68698735/13997210) hope its help to you . just replace `Row` instead of `Column` in this answer as per your need.

Comment: Added the other element as well. Basically need to create a gap between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10))
```

where you want the spacing to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code?

```
return  Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    child:Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
           children: [
              if (state.myClientRole == ClientRole.Broadcaster)
                InkWell(
                  onTap: context.read<VoiceChatCubit>().toggleMute,
                    child: 
                    Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          offset: const Offset(
                            0,
                            3.0,
                          ),
                          blurRadius: 1.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0,
                        ),
```

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: Can you remove volume Icon as a child in one row? Make sure volume Icon should be a separate widget for a row then it works perfectly.

child:
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: BlocBuilder<VoiceChatCubit, VoiceChatState>(

--------->

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: BlocBuilder<VoiceChatCubit, VoiceChatState>(